# autohotkey - customize keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I use a laptop with Italian keyboard, but I need the tilde ~ and the backtick ` characters, which my keyboard is not endowed with.

I got to know AutoHotKeys and it seems to fit. But I could not find a *map* to script. E.g., what are the key codes relative to the <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

Briefly, I want to do the following:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> = `

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>ì</kbd> = ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltGr): `<^>!` stands for AltGr so I do beleive you could use a script something like this:

```
<^>!':: ;send backtick
    SendInput, `` ; <- backtick is also the escape char, so we need to escape it first
    return

<^>!ì:: ;send backtick
    SendInput, ~
    return
```

I dont have AHK on my pc so couldn't try it, so you might have to tweak around a bit for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul. A last question: is this keys modification reversible? Once I run the .ahk script, is there a way to undo its effect?

Comment: @MatteoZambra The way I understand how autohotkey works you gonna have schedule this script to start up with windows manually, so to stop it you just need to remove the schedule, or the script file. If you need to stop the script without restarting you can just close AutoHotkey.